# Select2 "TypeError: a is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I've this code for create a `Select2` element from an input field:

```
var codigo_arancelario = $codigo_arancelario.val();

$codigo_arancelario.select2({
    placeholder: "Seleccione un estado",
    ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: function () {
            return Routing.generate('obtenerCodigoArancelario');
        },
        data: function (codigo_arancelario) {
            return {
                filtro: codigo_arancelario
            }
        },
        results: function (data) {
            var myResults = [];
            $.each(data.entities, function (index, item) {
                myResults.push({
                    'id': item.id,
                    'nombre': item.nombre
                });
            });
            return {
                results: myResults
            };
        }
    },
    formatNoResults: function () {
        return "No se encontró el código";
    },
    formatAjaxError: function () {
        return "No hay conexión con el servidor";
    }
});
```

But any time I try to use it I get this error on Firebug console:

> TypeError: a is undefined

I checked the Response headers and I got a `Content-Type application/json` and also I check the Request headers since I'm using Symfony2 in the server side and it send the `X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest`. The Symfony2 function return a JSON like this one:

```
{
   "valid":false,
   "entities":[
      {
         "id":101,
         "codigo":"4545",
         "descripcion":null
      },
      {
         "id":102,
         "codigo":"45455",
         "descripcion":"gfhgfhfghfgh"
      },
      {
         "id":103,
         "codigo":"45457",
         "descripcion":"etert"
      }
   ]
}
```

Where is the error on my code?

Comment: @MohitArora none of both it has data. The example JSON is what `data.entities` have

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e39ftb64/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select2 expects `[{text="john doe",id="1"},{text="jane doe",id="2"}]`

so you need to change `'nombre': item.nombre` to `'text': item.nombre`
it should look like followed:

```
 myResults.push({
       'id': item.id,
       'text': item.nombre
 });
```

Comment: @ReynierPM `item.nombre` is undefined i think you need `item.descripcion`

Answer (score -1):

May be your data is wrong formate :
data
Type: PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

see [jquery for ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: And? I don't follow you or doesn't found this helpful, sorry

Comment: use the debug at the breakpoint at line: var myResults = [];  print the result of the stack value.